# Need to modify a simple Python script (to process the other lines)?

Tags: python

The original post is here: [Remove words from a subtitle file that aren't in a wordlist (of common words)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550885/remove-words-from-a-subtitle-file-that-arent-in-a-wordlist-of-common-words)
They gave this script, but I need to add some more modifications:

```
import os
import re
from glob import glob

with open('words.txt') as f:
    keep_words = {line.strip().lower() for line in f}

for filename_in in glob('*.srt'):
    filename_out = f'{os.path.splitext(filename_in)[0]}_new.srt'
    with open(filename_in) as fin, open(filename_out, 'w') as fout:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if i == 2:
                parts = re.split(r"([\w']+)", line.strip())
                parts[1::2] = [w if w.lower() in keep_words else '*' for w in parts[1::2]]
                line = ''.join(parts) + '\n'
            fout.write(line)
```

Due to the 12th line: `if i == 2:` , it affects only the 3rd line of every `.srt` file. And I need to change this condition to process the other lines that are ordered in that way `i=3+4*Num` , since the `.srt` file structure is:

```
﻿1
00:02:14,970 --> 00:02:17,200
Stay with us while you're here in Los Angeles.

2
00:02:23,810 --> 00:02:26,880
Thank you.

3
00:02:26,880 --> 00:02:31,620
You are welcome, Mr. Med.
```

> (Optional)

Also can you find out how to process lines that are ordered like:

```
﻿1
00:02:14,970 --> 00:02:17,200
Stay with us while you're
here in Los Angeles.

2
00:02:23,810 --> 00:02:26,880
Thank you.

3
00:02:26,880 --> 00:02:31,620
You are welcome, Mr. Med.
```

Comment: For the first part, change `i == 2` to `i%4 == 2` - this will take i mod 4, so the third of every set of four lines.